# Print works, write doesn't. How come?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, csv

I've tested the code below, everything does as I expected it to except line 29. The final.write(invrow) doesn't actually write to the file. When I use a simple print invrow, it displays with no problems. I get no errors, what's happening here? What am I missing? What am I not doing properly?

```
import csv


inv = csv.DictReader(open('ireport.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
vbr = csv.DictReader(open('vb.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
mainr = csv.DictReader(open('main.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")

final = open('ireport2.tab', 'w')

inva = []
maina = []
vba = []


for row in inv:
    inva.append(row)

for row in mainr:
    maina.append(row)

for row in vbr:
    vba.append(row)

for invrow in inva:
    for mainrow in maina:
        try:
            if invrow['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE'] == mainrow['PART CODE']:
                invrow['MAINQTY'] = mainrow['ON-HAND']
                print invrow # works
                final.write(invrow) #doesn't work. Why?
        except TypeError:
            pass
        except ValueError:
            pass

final.close()
```

Comment: I can't say for certain, but what if you open the file as `wb` instead of just `w`? Can you describe what 'doesn't works' means?

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: `except TypeError: pass` is **really really suspicious**! Silently throwing away errors is not usually a good idea.

Comment: Take out the `TypeError` and `ValueError` exception handlers: they are most likely hiding the errors you're supposed to be seeing.

Comment: also you're explictly closing the file, `final.close()`, but this shouldn't be an issue if the program exits cleanly.  It's common to use the `with` statement in these situations. `with open(outfile, "w") as final:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print` automatically calls `str` on each argument. `write` does not.

So, if you pass a string, they'll both work, and in fact do the exact same thing. But if you pass something different, `write` will raise a `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`.

In your case, `invrow` is a dictionary, as returned by `csv.DictReader`. That's not a string, so you'll get the `TypeError`.

The reason you get no errors is that you're explicitly catching and throwing away `TypeError`s in your code, with that `except TypeError: pass` code.

---

Meanwhile, I think what you *wanted* to do here is to use a `csv.DictWriter` to write each row:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(final, inv[0].keys())
```

Then:

```
writer.writerow(invrow)
```

---

As a side note, you could simplify this tremendously. For example, a `DictReader` is an iterable; if you want to make a list of it, just call `list` on it, don't loop over it and `append` one by one. Like this:

```
inva = list(inv)
maina = list(main)
vba = list(vb)
```

But really, you only need to change the "inner" one, `maina`, into a `list`; the outer one, `inva`, you can just loop directly over the `DictReader`. And `vba`, you never use at all.

Also, if you use a `with` statement, you don't need the explicit `close`. And this has the side benefit that if your program quits in the middle with an exception, the file will be flushed and closed, so you can see what got written right before the error.

Finally, if you're going to use a `try`/`except` to handle exceptions and continue past them, you *really* want to have it print or log something so you know that it happened. In fact, I'd suggest leaving the `try` out during initial development, until you know that it works on non-broken files, and only adding it when you start dealing with broken files.

Putting it all together:

```
with open('main.txt', 'rU') as mainf:
    main = list(csv.DictReader(mainf, dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
with open('ireport.txt', 'rU') as invf, open('ireport2.tab', 'w') as finalf:
    inv = csv.DictReader(invf, dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t")
    final = csv.DictWriter(finalf, dialect='excel-tab', delimiter="\t",
                           fieldnames=inv.fieldnames)
    for invrow in inv:
        for mainrow in main:
            if invrow['\xef\xbb\xbfPART_CODE'] == mainrow['PART CODE']:
                invrow['MAINQTY'] = mainrow['ON-HAND']
                final.writerow(invrow)
```

Comment: I'll give this a go. As you might guess I've still very green to programming and everyone's insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think this is it, but since others gave good answers, you might as well need this one as final desperate fix.

I managed to get a similar bug weeks ago, also working with txt files. As far as i know you can't save some unicode/ascii/others symbols into txt files, such as ♥☻☺♦♣♠ on specific circunstances, i'll show you 2 examples:

1: This would crash it:

```
printablelog = open("examplefile.txt", "a")
printablelog.write("An example ♥☻☺♣ とかちそのラヒイスハレラテ and more text")
printablelog.close()
```

2: this would save it in bytes and since it encode it that way, you won't get errors:

```
printablelogfixed = open("example.txt", "ab")
printablelogfixed.write(bytes("An example ♥☻☺♣ とかちそのラヒイスハレラテ and more text", 'UTF-8')) 
printablelogfixed.close()
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You would just need to call toString() or a similar method on the object you're trying to write. Some languages would implicitly convert it to a writeable object, but you'll need to be more explicit with Python.

Comment: There is no `toString` method in Python. The nearest equivalent would be `__str__`, but you should almost never call that directly.

Comment: If dealing with a dict then you could call `''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in adict.items())`

Comment: Well, you _could_, but why? For example, given the dict `{1: '2', 3: '4'}`, that would give you `'3412'`, which is unlikely to be useful anywhere. What you probably want is `str(adict)`, or `repr(adict)`, or `json.dumps(adict)`, or `pickle.dumps(adict)`, or something else useful. Or, in the OP's actual case, `adict` _is_ actually what he wants, he just doesn't want to be passing it to `file.write`, but to `csv.DictWriter.writerow`…

Comment: str(adict) sounds a lot like a similar method to toString() as I mentioned in my answer. Sounds like you're just getting pedantic.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's "pedantic" in the same way Python is being pedantic when it raises an `AttributeError` on `adict.toString()`, or `adict.str()`. But I don't consider telling people how to actually write code that works, or at least giving them enough information that they can search for it in the docs (compare [this](site:docs.python.org str) to [this](site:docs.python.org toString)), to be overly pedantic. If you don't know even the basics of Python, why try to answer Python questions?

Comment: It's not the code itself that matters, it's the idea behind this. OP can research the correct method themselves and come to the resolution on their own, now that they know the problem, which is far more valuable.